# Make jQuery UI Tooltip reposition after Ajax loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am trying to implement an ajax-loaded tooltip which should contain an HTML table.

At first the tooltip displays a "loading..." text while the ajax call is performed, and then when the HTML data is received, it is used as the tooltip content.

The problem is that the tooltip position seems to be calculated only at the beginning, when the "loading..." is displayed, and not again when the tooltip content changes.

The tooltips are initialized with the following code:

```
$('.my_tooltip').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        tooltip_url = $this.data('tooltip-url'),
        cache_id = tooltip_url || '',
        opts = $.extend({}, {
            content: function(done) {
                if(tooltip.cache[cache_id]) {
                    return tooltip.cache[cache_id];
                }

                if(tooltip_url) {
                    Ajax.get($this.data('tooltip-url'), {}, {
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function(data) {
                            tooltip.cache[cache_id] = data;
                            done(tooltip.cache[cache_id]);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            done('Error while loading data!');
                        }
                    });

                    return 'Loading...';
                }

                return $this.attr('title');
            },
            items: $this,
            tooltipClass: $this.data('tooltip-class') || ('age-tooltip' + (!tooltip_id && !tooltip_url ? '-auto' : ''))
        }, options);

    $this.tooltip(opts);
});
```

Here is the tooltip while loading, at this time the tooltip does fit the viewport.
[image: Loading]

And here is how it looks after loading, as you see the tooltip did not automatically reposition, so you can see less than half of it.
[image: After loading]

In this case, if it had moved over the tooltip-ed element, it would be fully visible, however even if I let the tooltip disappear and then move the mouse again to hover, having it loaded from the local tooltip cache, it won't reposition.

I have looked into the `position` property for the tooltip, however if possible I'd like to avoid the need to manually specify it, and let the plugin handle it automatically.

Is there a way to have the tooltip positioned where the most of it will be visible **after** the ajax loading?

EDIT:

I tried @Stphane's solution, with the position `{my: 'left top+15', at: 'left bottom', of: this, collision: 'flipfit'}` however its not positioned correctly, seems to ignore the `top`/`bottom` part and instead takes the certer, as shown here:

[image: Wrong position]

Looking in the console, I see

> Error: no such method 'instance' for tooltip widget instance

which I guess might be due to the fact that we are still using jQuery UI version 1.10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage `using` property (being a callback/hook) documented on [jQuery UI position method](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)

> When specified, the actual property setting is delegated to this callback.

#### The cleaner approach

… is to use the `tooltip` instance getter to apply the right position as soon as possible:

```js
var tooltip = {cache: []},
    posSetter = function () {
        // 1.10.4 code
        $('.ui-tooltip').position({
        // 1.12.1
        // this.tooltip('instance').bindings.filter('.ui-tooltip').position({
            // Put the values that fit your need
            my: 'left top+15', at: 'left bottom', of: this, collision: "flip fit"
          })
        ;
    };

$('.my_tooltip').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    ownPosSetter = posSetter.bind($this),
    tooltip_url = $this.data('tooltip-url'),
    cache_id = tooltip_url || '',
    opts = $.extend({}, {
      content: function(done) {
        if (tooltip.cache[cache_id]) {
          return tooltip.cache[cache_id];
        }

        if (tooltip_url) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            let content = "<div style='height:200px;width:300px'>Content Loaded!</div>";
            tooltip.cache[cache_id] = content;
            done(content);
            setTimeout(ownPosSetter, 100);
          }, 2000);
          return 'Loading...';
        }

        return $this.attr('title');
      },
      items: $this,
      tooltipClass: 'age-tooltip-auto'
    }, {position: {using: ownPosSetter}});

  $this.tooltip(opts);
});
```

```css
div.contents {
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js">
<!-- 
< link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" / >
< script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" >
-->
</script>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents my_tooltip" title="Some content" data-tooltip-url="//somewhere.com">Has tooltip</div>
<div class="contents my_tooltip" title="Some content" data-tooltip-url="//somewhereelse.com">Has tooltip</div>
<div class="contents" id="log"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="contents"></div>
```

Comment: This could work, I'll try it as soon as I can, I'll just need to change the code to work based on the height rather than the width, thanks!

Comment: There is a better way than using an Interval. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari  it seems that the "setInterval alternative" section in my answer doesn't work either with `1.10.4`. I spent some time on this, I wish you told about the version constraint earlier.  We will find a way though.

Comment: You are absolutely right, and I am sorry to have wasted your time, I didn't write it 'cause I was sure I was on latest version, and only the error message in the console made me realize I was wrong

Comment: @MatteoTassinari As a workaround, all you have to do is directly look for the tooltip HTMLDOMElement instead of relying on the tooltip plugin instance: I changed this `this.tooltip('instance').bindings.filter('.ui-tooltip').position({` with `$('.ui-tooltip').position({` (Plus script and css link to the appropriate version). Check my update.

Comment: Thanks for the new input, but wouldn't `$('.ui-tooltip')` select **all** tooltips instead of only the current one?

Comment: Yes but the plugin seems to handle tooltips with a single HTMLElement. You can see that the code works like this. Otherwise we would have to find how the plugin associate a tooltip HTMLElement with a particular node in order to target the right one while setting the position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166678/discussion-between-matteo-tassinari-and-stphane).